# Azure artrifacts npm registry and authentication in Azure Pipeline

Tags: .net, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-install

I have problem with authentication in my app. I build it in my Azure Pipeline using dotnet publish where I run npm install. I have configured .npmrc file because I use two registries (one npm and the other one from Azure Artifacts). I still received 401 unathenticate.

How I can authenticate to my registry using PAT? PAT is correctly set.
`@first_registry:registry=https://myregistry/:_authToken=${token} always-auth=true` not work

Answer (score 1):

For authentication with your pipeline, it's recommended to use the [npm authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/npm-authenticate-v0?view=azure-pipelines) instead of using PAT.

> For authentication with your pipeline, Azure Artifacts recommends
> using the [npm authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/npm-authenticate-v0?view=azure-pipelines). When using a task runner like gulp or
> Grunt, it's important to add the npm authenticate task to the
> beginning of your pipeline. By doing so, your credentials are injected
> into your project's .npmrc file and persisted during the pipeline run,
> enabling subsequent steps to use the credentials in the configuration
> file.

So, please try to add the [npm authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/npm-authenticate-v0?view=azure-pipelines) at the beginning of your pipeline (at lease before the `npm install` and `dotnet publish` steps.)

```
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: .npmrc                ## Path to the npmrc file
    customEndpoint: #Optional          ## Comma-separated list of npm service connection names for registries from external organizations. For registries in your org, leave this blank
```

Please note that, to grant your pipeline access to your feed, make sure you set the `build service` role to `Contributor` in your feed settings.

Please see [Pipeline authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cyaml#pipeline-authentication) for details.

Comment: @marentinno37 May I know if above answer helps? Just want to see if there's anything I can do for you.